# Using Symbols with Prepared Statement parameters in JAVA

Tags: java, jdbc, prepared-statement

How do I used % in the parameter for the code below? it works if I just use it directly in the query without the rset.setString(). Thanks!

```
    try (Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(connection);
         PreparedStatement prepstmt = con.prepareStatement("SELECT {fn SUBSTRING(VS_TABLE_KEY,3,18)} FROM VP_SD_TABLE WHERE {fn SUBSTRING(VS_DESCRIPT,3,62)} LIKE ?");
         ResultSet rset = prepstmt.executeQuery()

    ) {
        prepstmt.setString(1,"DI%");
        while (rset.next()) {
            System.out.println(rset.getString("VS_TABLE_KEY"));
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(1);
    }
```

Comment: What happened when you tried that code?

Comment: returns no results

Comment: You need to give an alias to the `substring()` expression. Your result set does not have a column name `VS_TABLE_KEY`

Comment: So you think the alias is keeping it from working? If I use this it works as-is though. "SELECT {fn SUBSTRING(VS_TABLE_KEY,3,18)} FROM VP_SD_TABLE WHERE {fn SUBSTRING(VS_DESCRIPT,3,62)} LIKE 'DI%'"

Comment: I tried what you said @a_horse_with_no_name and it did not work. I see other posts similar to mine but everything I try doesn't work.

Comment: Don't execute the query as part of the try-with-resources. Create the resultset but don't run `executeQuery()` there. The setString has no effect that way.

Answer (score 2):

You're executing the query before you set the parameter. You should get an exception when you run this code, not just an empty result set.

Comment: Thanks! I've been working 10 hour shifts and things were starting to get hairy. Can't believe I was overlooking that.